# Unable to install mysql-server, getting error you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, server, package-management, mysql, dependencies

using the following command

1.sudo apt update 
2.sudo apt install mysql-server

**Getting below error**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Any help ?**

Comment: Remove whatever non-Ubuntu repository you added. Uninstall ALL packages that you successfully installed from that repository. Then run `sudo apt update` to refresh you database of available packages. Then install `mysql-server` from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: We don't know your release, nor what 3rd party sources (if any) you've added so cannot check if they're appropriate for your system (they will create *dep* issues if they aren't), so user535733's comment is the best we can do thus far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

my friend. It seems you have a bug with repositories.

So first, remove all non-official repositories from the distribution. Or third-party repositories.

Then, run

```
sudo apt update
```

Then you can install MySQL 8 by adding the official repository

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
```

Refresh APT again

```
sudo apt update
```

And perform the MySQL installation

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

And also you can install the client.

[Here](https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-and-configure-mysql-on-ubuntu/) is the reference.It should be enough.

Comment: Reading package lists... Error!
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: getting above  error while using 
sudo apt update

Comment: So first, remove all non-official repositories from the distribution. Or third-party repositories.

how to remove that sorry but i am new in that